Nginx fastcgi_read_timeout and keepalive_timeout
I'm trying to understand the difference between fastcgi_read_timeout and keepalive_timeout. I'm start looking at the configuration of an app that was made before me, that app is using Nginx + php-fpm + PHP, and I can see only keepalive_timeout but not fastcgi_read_timeout in configs.
If fastcgi_read_timeout is not set, the timeout will happen when it reaches the value of keepalive_timeout or not? What if I have both set, which one is in higher priority?
